# how to make scala type volatile on purpose

Tags: scala, types

According to http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#volatile-types, types are volatile when they adhere to specific conditions. Is it possible to make a type volatile (e.g. by an annotation) which is not of that form? What possible alternatives are there?

My use case is the following: I want to write a library, which exposes types `A` and `B` with `A <: B` and `B` is volatile. Then as a user of this library, I want to be able to overwrite a value of type `A` with one of type `B`:

```
trait TraitB {
  def doSomething: Unit
}

trait Library {
  type A
  type B <: A with TraitB
}

object LibraryUser {
  val library: Library = ???

  trait T {
    val x: library.A
  }

  object U extends T {
    val x: library.B = ???
  }
}
```

This fails with the error:

> error: overriding value x in trait T of type LibraryUser.library.A;
>   value x has a volatile type; cannot override a member with non-volatile type

But when I make `A` volatile, this succeeds. Currently, I make `A` volatile by making it a subclass of an abstract type `Abstract` which will just be `Any` in the implementation and otherwise not used:

```
trait TraitB {
  def doSomething: Unit
}

trait Library2 {
  protected type Abstract
  type A <: Any with Abstract
  type B <: A with TraitB
}

trait Library2ImplementationHelper {
  this: Library2 =>
  override type Abstract = Any
}

object Library2User {
  val library: Library2 = ???

  trait T {
    val x: library.A
  }

  object U extends T {
    val x: library.B = ???
  }
}
```

This compiles and works fine, but `Abstract` is a little bit artificial and I wonder if there's an other way.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the [`@volatile` annotation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/annotations.html), which will let the compiler know the `var` should be volatile. It should behave the same way as the equivalent Java annotation.

We can prove this by building a simple class in a file `SoVolatile.scala`:

```
class SoVolatile {
  @volatile var boom = 5
}
```

Then on the command line, go to the directory with that class and run:

```
$ scalac SoVolatile.scala
$ javap -verbose -private SoVolatile
```

Inside that we find the line `private volatile int boom;`. This is a little easier to find if you run this on the command line:

```
$ javap -verbose -private SoVolatile | grep "private volatile"
```

Comment: no, this has nothing to do with the volatile annotation, but is about volatile types in scala (they have nothing in common except their name)